# Command Line shows only jdk 20 version of java, not others

Tags: java, cmd, java-8, javac

I want to see the list of all jdk versions available in my system. However, when I type in java and javac version to the cmd line, it gives me only jdk 20 version. How can I do an implementation to see other jdk versions as well in the list?

```
C:\Users\USER>java --version
java 20 2023-03-21
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20+36-2344)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20+36-2344, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\Users\USER>javac --version
javac 20

C:\Users\USER>
```

I just typed `java --version` and `javac --version` commands to see jdk versions exist in my computer. Due to my assignment, I need jdk8 version. How can solve the problem in order to see the version I need?

Comment: Use the full path to your java installation, so something like `C:\Program Files\jdk8\bin\java --version` or whatever the correct path is where you installed java 8

Comment: _Due to my assignment, I need jdk8 version_ Set your JAVA_HOME to point to Jdk 8.

Comment: Not only the `JAVA_HOME` but also the `PATH`.

Comment: @PradeepSimha that doesn't help if you're running java from the command line. It will still run what's in the `PATH`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yup my bad I missed it, yes PATH variable also.

Comment: This is standard Operation System problem, more precisely from the used Command Line program. Usually (most versions) the system search the executables, if not using absolute path, in the directories given in the `PATH` environment variable. The first found executable will be executed. `java --version` or `javac --version` does **not** show all existing installations, it *only* shows the version being executed. (`JAVA_HOME` is **not** used by Java itself, some *external* tools use it instead of relying on the `PATH`)

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have big headaches if you try to handle multiple java versions manually. The best option is to delegate this to a third party tool, quite some already exists to overcome the issue. The best one and recommended by several frameworks (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started.installing.cli.sdkman) is sdkman:

https://sdkman.io/

Follow windows installation:
[https://sdkman.io/install#:~:text=Windows%20installation](https://sdkman.io/install#:%7E:text=Windows%20installation)

Then do:

```
sdk list java
```

You will see something like:

```
================================================================================
 Vendor        | Use | Version      | Dist    | Status     | Identifier
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Corretto      |     | 21           | amzn    |            | 21-amzn             
               |     | 21.0.1       | amzn    |            | 21.0.1-amzn         
               |     | 20.0.2       | amzn    |            | 20.0.2-amzn         
               |     | 20.0.1       | amzn    |            | 20.0.1-amzn         
               |     | 17.0.9       | amzn    |            | 17.0.9-amzn         
               |     | 17.0.8       | amzn    |            | 17.0.8-amzn         
               | >>> | 17.0.7       | amzn    | installed  | 17.0.7-amzn         
               |     | 11.0.21      | amzn    |            | 11.0.21-amzn        
               |     | 11.0.20      | amzn    |            | 11.0.20-amzn        
               |     | 11.0.19      | amzn    |            | 11.0.19-amzn        
               |     | 11.0.18      | amzn    | local only | 11.0.18-amzn        
               |     | 8.0.392      | amzn    |            | 8.0.392-amzn        
               |     | 8.0.382      | amzn    |            | 8.0.382-amzn        
               |     | 8.0.372      | amzn    | installed  | 8.0.372-amzn
```

Install what you need with:

```
sdk install java 20.0.2-amzn
```

Then switch among versions with:

```
sdk use java 20.0.2-amzn
```